# C++(11) "High Performance" Concurrent Single Writer(s)

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, boost, mutex

I have an object `B`, composed of 10 double values.
The double values are produced by a sensor which communicates
via ethernet and sends out updates once every 1-2 milliseconds.
Instances of `B` must be used at 2 other places in the program to
do some calculations and visualization.

In another thread, an object `A`, holding ~1000 double values is updated every 4-10 milliseconds using another sensor.

Both objects have a time signature (procured by using `boost::chrono::high_resolution_clock` when the sensor's update arrives)

Now I want to use two objects `A` and `B` that have been updated at nearly
the same time to calculate some values for an object `C`.
This should be done while both threads are running, and the output
used to do some visualization, computing averages, etc.
The whole procedure is running for 1-2 hours and
only instances of calculated `C`s are used after that,
instances of `A` and `B` are not longer needed.

What is the recommended method (or design pattern) to implement this communication and data sharing between the threads ?

At the moment, this whole construct is badly implemented, and
the thread composing `A` communicates directly with the one composing `B`
without using synchronization methods like mutexes.

- Should I use lockless double ended queues for storing `A` and `B`s
  and read from this in the thread composing `C`?
- Should I use an (thread-safe) observer pattern like `boost::signals2` to "send" the instances of `A` and `B` ?
- Or something different ?

Comment: Is `A` (`B`) should be see as *coherent* block or `std::atomic<double>` as members is possible.

Comment: Just a note: there is network delay, two readings that arrive at the same time does not mean they occurred at roughly the same time

Comment: @SelçukCihan You're right. But in this case, there is no other option than to assume both sensor readings can be fetched at the same time relative to one another.

Comment: Read it carefuly, but failed to understand the question. I'd suggest adding some pseudo-code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you do your computations and all on a PC and an OS without real-time guarantees. So as long as you're in a millisecond area you're not under hard real-time constraints. Therefore, it is not absolutely necessary to use lockfree data structures. But you can. They have good performance as well. You can use boosts lockfree data structures for that, if you'd like. But you might want a `pop()` function that blocks until the queue is not empty, because otherwise you need to do a busy wait or otherwise use a semaphore or condition variable of some kind in order to wait for a state where the queue is not empty.

You have low contention, and only a few threads. Locking a mutex under low contention usually takes in the order of 25ns. So this is not an issue. Memory allocations are also usually very fast nowadays, usually less than 100ns on average. So here's my take:

- Use an `std::queue<std::packaged_task<void()>>` as a task queue. You may also decide to enqueue `std::function<void()>` instead of `std::packaged_task<void()>()` if you don't need `std::future`s for the result of the computation. Protect accesses to it with a `std::mutex`. Have a `std::condition_variable` that is there to wait for the queue to be non-empty. I once implemented [a generic blocking concurrent queue on github](https://github.com/ralphtandetzky/cpp_utils/blob/master/concurrent_queue.h) which is more efficient than that, but uses only standard library means. You just have to specify the template argument to be `T=std::packaged_task<void()>` and you'll have the data structure you need.
- Create a thread `std::thread` that does nothing but to execute the incoming tasks. To exit the thread set some `std::atomic<bool>` flag in the last task of the thread, so the thread stops executing and you can `join()` it gracefully. Again, you can put that functionality into a class. The destructor of the class should tell the task executing thread to stop and do the `join()`. I implemented such a [class in the same repository on github](https://github.com/ralphtandetzky/cpp_utils/blob/master/parallel_executor.h). You're free to use it.
- Now you can pass tasks to the task executor from your two threads that receive data from the hardware. Just pass appropriate lambdas to the task executor that do the work that needs to be done. In the case you decide to use my implementation you can write something like

  ```
  void receiveData( const Data & data, cu::ParallelExecutor & executor )
  {
      executor.addTask( [=]{ /* Do something with `data` */ } );
  }
  ```

This way everything is thread-safe, has low overhead and high performance.

Comment: [formatting]: code within list requires additional tabulation.